# How do I make route navigation linear in react-route 6 with reactjs 17

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Example

User navigates from **"/"** to **"/orders"** in **"/orders"** navigates to **"/orders/products"** to add a product to the order, after adding the product to the order it is redirected to **"/orders"**. But if he clicks the back button while on the orders page the browser goes to **"/orders/products"** the way I would like is that if the user clicks the browser back he goes back to the route that I determine,
which would be **"/"** and not **"/orders/products"**

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can start using the redirects earlier in the flow and maintain the history stack you desire.

| Action | History Stack | Path | Back Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| initial | `["/"]` | `"/"` | ~ |
| PUSH "/orders" | `["/", "/orders"]` | `"/orders"` | `"/"` |
| REPLACE "/orders/products" | `["/", "/orders/products"]` | `"/orders/products"` | `"/"` |
| REPLACE "/orders" | `["/", "/orders"]` | `"/orders"` | `"/"` |

To use imperative navigation in `react-router-dom` v6 use the `useNavigate` hook.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

Interface:

> ```
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: State }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

Import and use in the component:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();
```

To do a PUSH navigation:

```
navigate("/orders");
```

To do a REPLACE redirect:

```
navigate("/orders/products", { replace: true });
```

If you needed to send any route state along with the navigation:

```
navigate("/orders/products", { state: 'some state value' });
```

Comment: I didn't understand how to use it on react-route 6

Comment: @JoandreiyCordeiro Navigation, the act of, didn't change between versions, you still either push or replace routes. The function used to navigate, however, did change. Is this your question then, how to navigate in `react-router-dom` v6? Can you update your question to include what your code is doing, or trying to do?

Comment: My intention is that, if I PWA, I don't have a back button inside the pages, but use the browser's back button to go to the route that I determine and not the route that is stored in the browser's history. If the user presses the Android back button it will also work.

Comment: @JoandreiyCordeiro I added details about how to navigate in RRDv6. Does that help answer your question?

Comment: Still not resolved. I would like that every time the user clicks the browser's back button, the browser does not use the route from his history, but the route that I specify. Sorry if my question may be confusing.

Comment: @JoandreiyCordeiro That is the only thing the browser's back button can do, you generally can't override that. You ***can*** however provide your own in-UI back button that navigates however you please. Like I said though, if you manage all your "forward" navigations correctly, then the browser's back navigation ***can only*** go back to what you want it to.

Comment: @JoandreiyCordeiro You might be able to set a listener for a "POP" navigation action, and programmatically issue a navigation elsewhere.